# Question about jetson Nano and rsync

Tags: partitioning, nvidia, mount, ssd, rsync

Recently I bought jetson nano of Nvidia, with eMMC. Unfortunely the eMMC has very little space so I decided to buy an external ssd to increase the space. I guy from the nvidia forum helped me a bit, but still I don't know what to do next. He told to use rsync on user/local on the mounted ssd, afterwards alter the /etc/fstab I did it and I think it okay (picture 2-3) .

I want to ask if I want to download a program or run python how do i choose to install/run it on the ssd and not in the eMMC?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAwmn.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You should create two partitions on ssd, mount one in your `/home` and another on `/usr/local`.

Comment: excuse my ignorance could you please explain it further I have like 64 gb left on my ssd. What I would achieve if I use again rsync on with /home on my ssd?

Comment: In that case, you can make a folder named `home` in `/usr/local` and do `ln -s /usr/local/home /home` or do your programming related work in `/usr/local/home` itself.